# how to make where clause statement in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

im newbie in elasticsearch,
i want to create a query to search document using multiple parameters.

when i use one parameter, its work.

[image]

but when i use where / or statement it goes wrong.
[image]

what should i do?
i want to make query like this :

> select * from motorvehicle_table where nama_kendaraan = "toyota" and
>   tahun_kendaraan = 2016 and tipe_kendaraan = "Non-Truck"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the parenthesis. Try this query instead:

```
GET /motorvehicle/product/_search?q=nama_kendaraan:toyota+AND+tahun_kendaraan:2015+AND+tipe_kandaraan:"Non-Truck"
```

Comment: your query is not work broo. {
   "statusCode": 400,
   "error": "Bad Request",
   "message": "child \"uri\" fails because [\"uri\" must be a valid uri]",
   "validation": {
      "source": "query",
      "keys": [
         "uri"
      ]
   }
}

Comment: How do you run your query?